# Sublime Text 2 - brackets highltighting

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++, sublimetext

Anyway to have similar bracket highlighting with Sublime Text 2, as that of Notepad++ (and for that matter the tab highlighting), NB the vertical lines for both.

[image: Bracket highlighting]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're looking for. Did the answer below really solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to install the [brackethighlighter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/BracketHighlighter) plugin.  If you haven't enabled Package Control in Sublime yet, you can find instructions on how to enable it [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation).

When enabled, it should provide similar gutter icons:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. @darkcharl - I actually have that plugin installed but I do not see anything that resembles the NP++ red vertical line between open/close brackets as per screenshot (and don't see the vertical line representing tab indents too).

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I added a screenshot on how it looks in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the open close brackets to the left of the numbers (and the underline affect on the selected brackets) but I'm not seeing anything else (down arrows, vertical tab lines). Strange. Appreciate your response though.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate that experimental feature in [Bracket Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) extension, just adding to the config file this line:

```
"content_highlight_bar" : true
```

C&P from the official Guide:

> content_highlight_bar
>
> An experimental setting which can enable the display of a vertical bar
>   that extends from the line containing the opening bracket to the line
>   with the closing bracket. Takes a boolean true or false. When
>   align_content_highlight_bar is set to false, the bar will be shown on
>   the first column regardless of indent level of the brackets. When
>   align_content_highlight_bar is set to true, the bar will be aligned at
>   the bracket indent level.

There is a bunch of information about this and other features in the Customization Chapter of the extension User Guide, [here.](https://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/)